# Consuming from added partitions in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a `KafkaConsumer` and use manual partition assignment. To distribute partitions I use `consumer.partitionsFor(topicId)` in regular intervals to detect added partitions, because the job runs forever and I want to support this case. However, this always returns initial list of partitions, unless I restart the consumer.

Is there a way detect added partitions from consumer? What to poll or listen for?

Comment: I also tested the automatic assignment, and it seems to also not detect added partitions.

Comment: please show your code about automatic assignment, yes, manual can not detect this change, but I believe the `subscribe` could handle it.

Comment: It's just `consumer.subscribe(singletonList("my_topic"))`. Then I check the output of `consumer.assignment()` and it doesn't change after I add the partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KafkaConsumer` has a [configuration property](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs) "metadata.max.age.ms", which defaults to 5 minutes. That means, that each call to `consumer.partitionsFor` will return cached copy for that time and only then fetch new metadata.

Setting the property to `0` fetches new metadata each time.

Comment: the problem is that `metadata.max.age.ms` affects all calls that care about this parameter, not just `partitionsFor`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is in the process of the partition reassign when you query by the `assignment()` method.  You could sleep 5 seconds and then check this to test it.

> Get the set of partitions currently assigned to this consumer. If subscription happened by directly assigning partitions using assign(Collection) then this will simply return the same partitions that were assigned. **If topic subscription was used, then this will give the set of topic partitions currently assigned to the consumer (which may be none if the assignment hasn't happened yet, or the partitions are in the process of getting reassigned)**.

Comment: I waited at least 30 seconds

Comment: is it the only consumer of this group ?

Comment: two consumers in two jvms, but i print output of `assignment()` on both